# CSS :last-of-type and :before is not working

Tags: css

I have an issue with applying `:last-of-type` and `:before`.

I have the following:

```
.stepwizard-row:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  content: " ";
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #97D3FD;
}
.stepwizard-row:before:last-of-type {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  content: " ";
}
```

However, the `:before:last-of-type` doesn't seem to have any effect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: From Spec - *Only one **pseudo-element** may appear per selector, and if present **it must appear after the sequence of simple selectors** that represents the subjects of the selector.*

Comment: @Harry `::before` is a pseudo-element but `:last-of-type` is a pseudo-class. Is possible use both

Comment: @blonfu: Please check which portion had been highlighted :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a wrong order, it should be:

```
.stepwizard-row:last-of-type:before {}
```

> **[CSS3 Selectors - 7. Pseudo-elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements)**
>
> **Only one pseudo-element may appear per selector**, and if present it must appear **after the sequence of simple selectors** that represents the subjects of the selector. *Note: A future version of this specification may allow multiple pseudo-elements per selector*.

By the way, you may get unexpected behavior by using `.class:last-of-type`, it *really* should work with elements, e.g. `.parent > div:last-of-type`.

> **[6.6.5.9. :last-of-type pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-of-type-pseudo)**
>
> Same as `:nth-last-of-type(1)`. The `:last-of-type` pseudo-class represents an element that is the last sibling of its type in the list of children of its parent element.